# extracting CNN features from middle layers

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to test the performance of each convolutional layer of my Convolutional Neural Network(CNN) architecture using SVM. I am using MatConvNet Matlab toolbox.

Layers are like that:
Conv1 Relu1 Pool1  (3x3, 32 features) -> Conv2 Relu2 Pool2  (3x3, 64 features) -> Conv3 Relu3 Pool3  (3x3, 128 features) ->Conv4 Relu4   (1x1, 256 features) -> Conv5  (1x1, 4 features)-> Softwamxloss

After training, I removed the loss layer

```
net.layers=net.layers(1 : end - 1);
```

I have the network looks like that
[image]

I can extract the features like that:

```
feats = vl_simplenn(net, im) ;
Feautre_L1(fea,:) = squeeze(feats(end).x);
```

similarly, I remove 2 more layers and extract 256 features from Conv4.
But when I moved to Conv3 the output feature is 7x7x128. 
I want to know that how can I used these features
i) Making a single vector 
ii) Averaging the values in depth?

Comment: Make a single vector with 7x7x128 =  6727 dimensions. If you stumble into other layer and the final vector would be too big, you might want to use some dimensionality reduction, such as PCA.

Comment: does it matters each 7x7 to make single vector by column-wise or row-wise?

Comment: "If you stumble into other layer " you mean combine features of two layers?

Comment: I don't think it matters, as long as you do it the same way every time.

Comment: Sorry about the "if you stumble into other layer" sentence, it wasn't very clear. In some cases, the output of a layer might end up having a big dimentionality when flattened into an array (for example 14x14x512 = 100.352). In my experience, reducing the dimentionality before training the SVM improved my results. This also is valid when combining features from two layers, as you've said.

Comment: Actually, I want to combine the features of multiple layers. I have 4 features from last layer and 256 from 2nd last convolutional layer and 6272 from 3rd last convolutional layer. The difference between using only 4 features with SVM and combining features from all three layers with SVM is 7%. Do you think it will improve more with using PCA? BTW, 7% increase in accuracy is for combination of 3 layers

Comment: I don't think so. In my opinion, you still have a small number of features. I would recommend some kind of dimensionality reduction if you were above 100k. Despite that, it wouldn't be too much work to run PCA on your data (I'm not too familiar with Matlab toolboxes, but I suppose you can find a easy-to-use PCA implementation). Just out of curiosity, using only the 3rd last convolutional layer (the one that outputs 6272 features) what is the accuracy in comparison to combining all three?

Comment: The testing accuracy of 3rd last convolutional layer is 73% and the combination of three layers is 80%

Comment: I see. You may want to increase the number of layers of your network as a way of increasing its learning capacity. Your network is fairly simple, considering what is being used nowadays.

Comment: Yes that's the other thing I want to try.

Comment: If you put these things in the answer so that I can accept that

Comment: Also can you please suggest some article for of combining CNN feature layers

Comment: Hey, @Addee, could you accept my answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Transforming a map into a feature vector:

In your case, you could turn the 7x7x128 map into an array with 6727 dimensions. In case you have an intermediate map, whose flattened array has a high-dimentionality (e.g., 100k-d), you may want to reduce its dimensions (through PCA, for example) because it probably contains a lot of redundancy in its features.

### Combining the output of your layers:

As for combining the features, there are many ways of doing it. An option that you've mentioned is to create a single vector concatenating the desired layers' outputs and train a classifier on top of that. This is known as *early fusion* [1], where you combine your features for a single representation before training.

Another possibility is to train a separate classifier for each feature (the output of each intermediate layer, in your case) and then, for a testing image, you combine the outputs/scores of those separate classifiers. This is known as *late fusion* [1].

### Extras:

An exploration you could perform is to investigate which layers you should select (either for early- or late-fusion) prior to training your SVM. This [2] is an interesting paper, where the authors explore something similar (analyzing the performance when using the output from the last few layers as features separately). As far as I remember, their investigation is within the context of transfer learning (using a model pre-trained in a similar problem to tackle/solve another task).

[1] [*"Early versus Late Fusion in Semantic Video Analysis"*](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Marcel_Worring/publication/221571875_Early_versus_late_fusion_in_semantic_video_analysis/links/0912f508932602eb9a000000.pdf)

[2] [*"CNN Features off-the-shelf: an Astounding Baseline for Recognition"*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.6382.pdf)

Comment: I just want to try PCA on the final features: total images are 11232 and feature for each image is 6532. so the feature matrix is like that 11232x6532. When I used PCA code:
[coeff, score] = pca(Feature);
the o/p of coeff is 11232x2500. it already reduce the features?

Comment: Yes, probably it has already reduced the number of features. PCA usually has a parameter that you can choose either the number of final features or the variance/energy you want to retain in the final features. So you can play with that to tune for the number of features you want.

Comment: I have posted this question. If you have you can check.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355404/pca-dimension-reducion-for-classification

Comment: About the late fusion in above paper the multimodal feature concatenation is score of learning model? like if there is 4 class model and three feature extraction layer. So for each layer there will be supervised learning model the output for class 1 image lets say is [1 1 3]. for 2 models the output is correct, however, it is wrong for 3rd model. Then [1 1 3] with label 1 for Class 1 it will again be input to the new supervised model?