# PCA Dimension reducion for classification

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am using Principle Component Analysis on the features extracted from different layers of CNN. I have downloaded the toolbox of dimension reduction from [here](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/drtoolbox/).

I have a total of 11232 training images and feature for each image is 6532. so the feature matrix is like that `11232x6532`
If I want top 90% features I can easily do that and training accuracy using SVM of reduced data is 81.73% which is fair. 
However, when I try the testing data which have 2408 images and features of each image is 6532. so feature matrix for testing data is `2408x6532`. In that case the output for top 90% feature is not correct it shows `2408x2408`.
and the testing accuracy is 25%. 
Without using dimension reduction the training accuracy is 82.17% and testing accuracy is 79%.
**Update:**
Where `X` is the data and `no_dims` is required number of dimensions at output. 
the output of this PCA function is variable `mappedX` and structure `mapping`.

```
% Make sure data is zero mean
    mapping.mean = mean(X, 1);
    X = bsxfun(@minus, X, mapping.mean);

    % Compute covariance matrix
    if size(X, 2) < size(X, 1)
        C = cov(X);
    else
        C = (1 / size(X, 1)) * (X * X');        % if N>D, we better use this matrix for the eigendecomposition
    end

    % Perform eigendecomposition of C
    C(isnan(C)) = 0;
    C(isinf(C)) = 0;
    [M, lambda] = eig(C);

    % Sort eigenvectors in descending order
    [lambda, ind] = sort(diag(lambda), 'descend');
    if no_dims < 1
        no_dims = find(cumsum(lambda ./ sum(lambda)) >= no_dims, 1, 'first');
        disp(['Embedding into ' num2str(no_dims) ' dimensions.']);
    end
    if no_dims > size(M, 2)
        no_dims = size(M, 2);
        warning(['Target dimensionality reduced to ' num2str(no_dims) '.']);
    end
    M = M(:,ind(1:no_dims));
    lambda = lambda(1:no_dims);

    % Apply mapping on the data
    if ~(size(X, 2) < size(X, 1))
        M = bsxfun(@times, X' * M, (1 ./ sqrt(size(X, 1) .* lambda))');     % normalize in order to get eigenvectors of covariance matrix
    end
    mappedX = X * M;

    % Store information for out-of-sample extension
    mapping.M = M;
    mapping.lambda = lambda;
```

Based on your suggestion. I have calculated the vector for the training data.

```
numberOfDimensions = round(0.9*size(Feature,2));
[mapped_data, mapping] = compute_mapping(Feature, 'PCA', numberOfDimensions);
```

Then using same vector for testing data:

```
mappedX_test = Feature_test * mapping.M;
```

Still the accuracy is 32%

Solved by doing subtraction:

```
Y = bsxfun(@minus, Feature_test, mapping.mean);
mappedX_test = Y * mapping.M;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're doing dimensionality reduction on both the training and testing data separately.  During training, you're supposed to remember the principal scores or basis vectors of the examples during training.  Remember that you are finding a new representation of your data with a new set of orthogonal axes based on the training data.  During testing, you repeat the exact same procedure as you did with the training data as you are representing the data with respect to these basis vectors.  Therefore, you use the basis vectors for the **training data** to reduce your data down.  You are only getting a `2408 x 2408` matrix because you are performing PCA on the test examples as it is impossible to produce basis vectors beyond the rank of the matrix in question (i.e. 2408).

Retain your basis vectors from the training stage and when it's time to perform classification in the testing stage, you must use the same basis vectors from the training stage.  Remember that in PCA, you must centre your data by performing mean subtraction prior to the dimensionality reduction.  To do this, in your code we note that the basis vectors are stored in `mapping.M` and the associated mean vector is stored in `mapping.mean`.  When it comes to the testing stage, make sure you mean subtract your test data with the `mapping.mean` from the training stage:

```
Y = bsxfun(@minus, Feature_test, mapping.mean);
```

Once you have this, finally go ahead and dimensionality reduce your data:

```
mappedX_test = Y * mapping.M;
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the code I am using. In that code `lambda` is Eigen values and `M` is Eigen vector. so you mean I should use same `M` which I have used for the training data?

Comment: Yes. Correct. The reduction is based on the training data as that is the basis you're building. The test data should be reduced with the same basis vectors. Doing it separately on the test data is incorrect.

Comment: Yes I have tested that and updated my question.. still it doesn't worked

Comment: You also need to mean subtract the test data with the same mean vector as the training data. Did you do that? You have to repeat *every step* as you did in the training stage. Mean subtract the test data with the mean feature vector of the training data, then do the multiplication.

Comment: Oh i missed that. Got it now :)

Comment: @Addee aha, I figured you missed that step :) I'll update my post for self-containment.  Glad you got it to work!

Comment: @Addee BTW, what is your accuracy now that you have it implemented correctly?

Comment: Its same without doing the dimension reduction. 79% testing accuracy and 82% training. Any recommendations to improve the accuracy?

Comment: @Addee Ah, this is one of the cases where PCA may not work.  I would recommend looking at Linear Discriminant Analysis since you are doing classification. LDA performs dimensionality reduction by also considering the basis vectors that maximally separate between the different classes. This is basically performing supervised dimensionality reduction. The toolbox you're using has support for LDA, so try using that and see what performance you get.  The basis vectors you get from LDA operate the same as PCA, so there's virtually no code change other than changing the flag from `PCA` to `LDA`.

Comment: @Addee One last thing to comment on is that when you perform LDA, there's no need to mean subtract the test data anymore as the LDA process does not do this as it is computing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a completely different matrix. If you are getting poor results, remove the part where you are mean normalizing prior to the reduction.

Comment: Is it normal for the LDA to take long time to compute Eigen values?

Comment: @Addee Yes unfortunately.  With PCA, people usually use the singular value decomposition as a quick step because the covariance matrix isn't explicitly needed.  LDA requires solving for the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a product of within-scatter and in-class scatter matrices (roughly) and these matrices require to be calculated first.  How much time does it take for you currently?

Comment: around an hour. But it automatically reduced it 3 features from 6532 as higher dim takes more time.. with 3 dimension data.. the training acc is too bad

Comment: @Addee ahhh. That's not good.  It would actually help if you gave me some idea on what your features are in your training set.  Can you provide some more detail regarding that?

Comment: I have this CNN arch: Conv1 Relu1 Pool1 (3x3, 32 features) -> Conv2 Relu2 Pool2 (3x3, 64 features) -> Conv3 Relu3 Pool3 (3x3, 128 features) ->Conv4 Relu4 (1x1, 256 features) -> Conv5 (1x1, 4 features)-> Softwamxloss. I am combining the features of Conv5, Conv4, and Conv3,. so that's why the feature length is 6532 (4+256+ 7*7*128). I am testing again as I have blocked that settings which reduce the dim to 3 in LDA code. They used that to save time.